# Regex for range of numbers

Tags: swift, regex

I am trying to build a regex to check if my string contains a number between < and >

The number goes from 1 to 435.
What I have so far :

```
^<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|4[0-2][0-9]|43[0-5])$>
```

give false if I add some content after

```
^<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|4[0-2][0-9]|43[0-5])*>
```

give true for <1231> rest of the string

Comment: If you can attach a validation function it would be much faster to try parse the string and validate the number with simple comparison.

Comment: the first regex is ok if you swap `$` and `>`

Comment: I don't think the swap works, at least not on the online tools

Comment: This is the result when you do the suggested swap https://regex101.com/r/AbciDn/1

Comment: The string I am using this regex on also has some text after the <###>

Comment: In that case you can omit the anchors `<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|4[0-2][0-9]|43[0-5])>`  https://regex101.com/r/AbciDn/2 or match what comes before and what comes after https://regex101.com/r/AbciDn/3

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match from 1 inclusive to 435 inclusive you could use your regex without the anchors `^` and `$` if there can be something before and/or after the match.

Note that in your regex `$>` should be `>$`

```
<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|4[0-2][0-9]|43[0-5])>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AbciDn/2)

If you want to match the whole line including `<..>` you could use:

```
^.*<([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|4[0-2][0-9]|43[0-5])>.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AbciDn/3)